# TypeError: interaction.options.getString is not a function discord.js v14 error

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror

I'm making a discord bot and am using discord v14.3.0.
I call `` const faction = interaction.options.getString(`${date}-faction`) ``
with `let date = Date.now()` above it. I am calling this in a module with `async execute(interaction) {}` and call that module in bot.js like this:

```
// if interaction is from bot
if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

const slashCom = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);

if (!slashCom) return;

try {
    await slashCom.execute(client, interaction);
 } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this 
 command!', ephemeral: true });
 }
```

inside a client on interaction create.
The application command data is this:

```
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('faction')
    .setDescription('Choose a faction to join.')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName(`${date}-faction`)
            .setDescription('The faction you want to join. (BurningShadows, WaterLight, or JadeDawn.)')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices({ 
                name: "BurningShadows", value: "BurningShadows" }, 
                { name: "WaterLight", value: "WaterLight" },
                { name: "JadeDawn", value: "JadeDawn" })
    ),
```

I have tried the other article on this but I did not find anything that solved my problem. What `console.log(interaction.options)` prints out is this:

```
{
intents: 46687,
 closeTimeout: 5000,
 waitGuildTimeout: 15000,
 shardCount: 1,
 makeCache: [Function (anonymous)],
 partials: [],
  failIfNotExists: true,
  presence: { status: 'online', user: { id: null } },
  sweepers: { threads: { interval: 3600, lifetime: 14400 } },
 ws: {
 large_threshold: 50,
  compress: false,
  properties: { os: 'darwin', browser: 'discord.js', device: 'discord.js' },
  version: 10,
  presence: { activities: [], afk: false, since: null, status: 'online' }
 },
 rest: {
 agent: [Getter],
 api: 'https://discord.com/api',
 authPrefix: 'Bot',
 cdn: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com',
 headers: {},
 invalidRequestWarningInterval: 0,
 globalRequestsPerSecond: 50,
 offset: 50,
 rejectOnRateLimit: null,
 retries: 3,
 timeout: 15000,
 userAgentAppendix: 'Node.js v16.17.0',
 version: '10',
 hashSweepInterval: 14400000,
 hashLifetime: 86400000,
 handlerSweepInterval: 3600000
 },
 jsonTransformer: [Function: toSnakeCase],
 shards: [ 0 ]
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the `interaction.options.getString`  not registered as function,  + date is not equivalent  as string,  so you might need  to use `.getValue` then convert it to String. You can use `DateTime` to make it as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option name is set to the current date when it is created, then you try to get it using `Date.now()` which will have a different value by that time.

### Original

I had this issue before but fixed it by changing `getString()` to just `get()`.

Comment: does not work I just get the same error but instead of getString() as an error I just get get() is not a funcion.

Comment: @RatInChat After reviewing your code, I've found the issue. When you create the command, you set the date in the option name but when you try to get it, you use a different date. When you do this, the option name still contains the original date so the option doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh then what could I do to fix that? I need the dates to be different so that it wont break when 2 people use it at a time.

Comment: @RatInChat I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish so I'm not sure how it could be fixed in your situation.

Comment: apparently its not the problem because I removed the date and it still gives me the error...?

Comment: Hmm thats weird, I can't think of anything else that would cause such an issue